# 'got tuple instead' python error when passing a string

Tags: python, sql

Im trying to pass a string varible to an sql query but I get the following error `got tuple instead` even though I'm passing a string.

> & When I use the following command
>   `command = ("INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES ('student')")` it works fine... any feedback is appreciated

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

con=psycopg2.connect(
    dbname= 'xxxxx', 
    host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    port= 'xxxx', 
    user= 'xxxxx', 
    password= 'xxxxxxxxx',
)
cur = con.cursor()

mystr="student"
print("Varible Type: ",type(mystr)) # output: Varible Type:  <class 'str'>
command = ("INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES (%s)",(mystr)) 
cur.execute(command)
con.commit()

cur.close() 
con.close()
```

> This code outputs the following

```
Varible Type:  <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFile.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur.execute(command)
TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead
```

Comment: command is a tuple, it contains the "INSERT INTO..." string and `mystr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using the `%` method of formatting in a way that doesn't abide the syntax.

Keep in mind I don't use pandas so I am providing multiples ways to pass in an argument, although I do use SQLite3.

So, how you want to do it:

```
command = ("INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES (%s)" % mystr)
```

The `.format` method:

```
command = ("INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES ({})".format(mystr)
```

Then there is the concatenation method:

```
command = "INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES (" + mystr + ")"
```

Which is harder and adds unnecessary code.

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are setting the value of `command` to be a two item tuple, this will only ever work if you pass it in directly to the function where this command takes place, for example in SQLite3 there is an `execute` function, you would pass in a string that executes something.

There is also the first method but as one single string, instead of a tuple of one string:

```
command = "INSERT INTO dev.roles (name) VALUES (%s)" % mystr
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped!